# Discord.py I am looking for make command to set role for everyone using the command

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def addrole(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Open")
    await ctx.add_roles(user, role)
```

but when I using this command . i getting this error (discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server')

Comment: use `guild`instead `server` they updated in the newest version of discord.py\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server` is changed to `guild` and its `Member.add_roles()`

Below is the revised code:

```py
import discord
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx):
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Open")
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: (discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions )

this error message when I edited my code :(